# How to add timestamp to created column with Copy Data activity of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have CSV files in Azure Blob Storage.
I have Copy Data activity to copy data to Azure SQL.
I have one extra column called Created in Azure SQL database table. All other columns are identical between CSV and DB.

I did notice build in feature in mapping where I could map timestamp to Created column.

Is possible to do with Copy Data activity or should I just do "Update table Set Created" with Lookup?

What is best way to add timestamp to created column when Copy Data activity has performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Copy Data activity.

Use add an **additional column**, to get the current timestamp.

[image]

[image]

### Source: CSV

[image]

### Sink: SQL Table

[image]

[image]

### Import schema

Select from dropdown, the additional column you created.

[image]

### Test Debug

[image]

[image]

Comment: Almost there. I have "Created" colum as datetime2 type in sink.  I don't get errors from applying solution presented in above and I get timestamp correctly to DB, but getting warning "Copying from column Created to column Created may have data truncation." What is best practise?

Comment: It means the column `created` in the destination DB is too short to hold the data. You can increase its length like eg: from varchar(20) to varchar(34).  Syntax: `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name column_type`   --> eg:  `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name varchar(34)`